# How to select a ComboBox item using a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I can't seem to figure out why the selected index does not work. I need to make the ComboBox index move from first item down to the last one. The point is I need to execute this function "loadtrainer2()" to all of the items in the ComboBox

Here is my code:

```
While READER.Read
    Dim count as integer

    id = READER.GetInt32("emp_id")
    count = count + 1

    ComboBox1.Items.Add(id)
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 1
End While

If count >= 1 Then
    loadtrainer2()
End If
```

Comment: Because nothing is selected.  You don't need the HasRows by the way.  If there aren't any rows, the while loop will skip the block.

Comment: Does `ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 1` ?  No it doesn't, so it's "False".  `i need to execute this function loadtrainer2() to all of the items in the combobox`  That sentence doesn't make sense.  Can you expand on that?

Comment: @LarsTech uhmmm. You see what I'm trying to fill the combobox for are ID of employees. So If they are employees they will fill the combobox and I need to select each ID and execute them to the loadtrainer2() function in order to update some sort of information to the table.

Comment: Users rarely find the Id of something useful - they dont often memorize the DB Id for all the employees, customer, products etc.  Rather than manually posting Ids as items, try binding the CBO to a DataTable and show the names

Comment: @Plutonix i just put it in the combobox to serve as storage of data so that they call all be read to my second function

Comment: But the question code shows the user selecting them.  You dont need to use UI controls to store data - datatables are ideal for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a few comments I've decided it would be easier to post an answer.

I would consider using a `DataTable` to do this instead. Something like:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
```

If you are wanting to display the values in a `ComboBox` then assign the properties accordingly:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
ComboBox1.DisplayMemeber = "emp_name" 'This is a guess on the column name
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "emp_id"
```

If you don't want to display the values then you don't need a `ComboBox` and instead just use the `DataTable` code.

Then instead of using `READER` you could loop through the `DataTable`:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    loadtrainer2(CInt(row("emp_id")))
Next
```

You would need to change your `loadtrainer2` method to accept the parameter `id`:

```
Private Sub loadtrainer2 (ByVal id As Integer)

End Sub
```